# R - shiny app - ERROR: Invalid git repo specification: 'ShinySky'

Tags: r, shinyapps, git-repo

I try to run a shiny app on R studio, I get the error
"ERROR: Invalid git repo specification: 'ShinySky'"
with the message at the console:
"there is no package called ‘shinysky’
Warning: Error in parse_repo_spec: Invalid git repo specification: 'ShinySky'"
Any ideas how to resolve the issue?

```
install.packages("shiny")
library(shiny)

 ui <- fluidPage(
     sliderInput(inputId ="num", label = "Choose the sample size", value=5, 
     min=1, max=25 ),
     plotOutput("hist")
     )
 server <- function(input, output, session) {
      output$hist <- renderPlot({
      hist(rnorm(input$num))
  })
  }
  shinyApp (ui, server)
```

Comment: How exactly are you "running" the shiny app? It's unclear what you are doing exactly to get this error message. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I added the code above. When I say "running" I mean this: R automatically sees this as an "app" and allows to run it as an app on a webpage.

Comment: This code works as-is. The [tag:git-repo] tag also makes no sense, given that you are running this in RStudio. Even if you are pushing this to shinyapps.io, that error makes no sense since `shinysky` is never referenced in the code.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure that's the whole code I'm running and that I'm getting this exact error message.